# CSS Two buttons next to each other, one in a form and one not

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to get these two buttons to line up side by side. The end of the form automatically throws out a new line.

```
<form>
....
<button id="regSubmit" class="sbutton"><span class="register">SIGN UP</span></button>
</form>
<button id="regReset" class="sbutton"><span class="reset">RESET FIELDS</span></button>
```

Comment: why can't the regReset button be in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With great difficulty, maybe.

Easiest thing to do is to add:

```
onClick="return false;"
```

To the second button. Although, by the look of it it's supposed to be a reset button for the form? Wouldn't `<input type="reset" />` be more suitable?

Comment: How is `onclick` related to aligning the buttons?

Comment: `onclick` allows you to put it inside the form without it submitting the form. As it turns out all that was needed was the right type of `input`.

Comment: Ha! I didn't realize that was the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't have regReset button in the form, maybe try hiding the regReset button outside of the form, and have a button inside the form that clicks it in javascript:

```
<form>
....
<button id="regSubmit" class="sbutton"><span class="register">SIGN UP</span></button>
<button id="regResetBtnClicker" onclick="document.getElementById('regReset').click();" class="sbutton"><span class="reset">RESET FIELDS</span></button>
</form>
<button id="regReset" style="display: none;" class="sbutton"><span class="reset">RESET FIELDS</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the second button to the right by adding a css rule:

```
#regReset { float: right}
```

or just by adding style to the button itself:

```
<button style="float: right" id="regReset" class="sbutton"><span class="reset">RESET FIELDS</span></button>
```